# how to leave my acvitity to continue run when the apps is not on front ?

Tags: android

I wrote some application that write to file the GPS location every 30 seconds. 
When the application is not on focus i want to continue to write to the file.

How to do it ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407907/how-to-keep-an-app-running-continually-with-gps-on?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible due to the lifecycle of an Activity. As soon as you lose focus or hide it it will go into the corresponding state of `onPause`, `onStop` or even `onDestroy` if its not needed anymore.

What you have to do in order to fix it to start a `Service`. There are different kind of services and in your case an unbounded background service would do the job.

You possibly want to start it in the `onStop()` and stop it at `onResume` methods

See here for more android documentation on services
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 1):

To get things to continu working after the app is send to the background, you would need to use a `Service` instead of a `Activity`.

Check out this link, the Android Developer website about services:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Also read this, about the fundamentals of Android apps:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html